# Can you have more than one runloop per thread on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading

Are there any possible way to create two or more run loop in one thread? Or one thread can have only one run loop?

My partner tells me, one thread is possible to have two or more run loop inside. And I doubt it. I had googled but found nothing. So, is it possible to have two or more run loop in one thread ?

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you want to achieve this...

Comment: I doubt what my partner said. I think it is impossible to have multi runloop in one thread. I remember one thread has only one run loop when I read apple official document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Apple's [documentation on NSRunLoop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Your application cannot either create or explicitly manage NSRunLoop
>   objects. Each NSThread object, including the application’s main
>   thread, has an NSRunLoop object automatically created for it as
>   needed.

Beyond that, I see no reason why you'd want to create more than one runloop per thread.

Comment: Is it possible one thread have more than one run loops? This document doesn't define such thing. It said we cannot create or manage runloop objects, but is it possible that the iOS use more than one run loop in one thread ?

Comment: @Toro - You cannot create run loops yourself for threads, and there is only one run loop returned by the system for any given thread, so that would indicate that there only can be one run loop for any thread.  Beyond a purely theoretical discussion, I don't even see how it would make sense to have more than one run loop per thread.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ask this question because I am confused about what my partner said.

Comment: @BradLarson In fact, you create more than RunLoop in a thread and there are mutiple situations when you might find that useful and optimizational.
I did that and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add this quote from [CFRunLoop Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/index.html) documentation

> There is exactly one run loop per thread. You neither create nor
>   destroy a thread’s run loop. Core Foundation automatically creates it
>   for you as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just want to make sure something at that time. And I am sure that one thread has only one runloop. Thanks anyway.